# How to convert a generic spreadsheet of contacts to an Outlook contact group?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a spreadsheet that has 3 columns: Name, Email address, Organization.

What is the best way to convert this to an Outlook 2010 Contact Group?   Or is this not possible?

A good answer would explain how to format the column headers, which file type is best to use, and any tips on using the "Import from File" or alternate method from Outlook. I have access to MS Word, MS Access, MS Excel as well as a text editor to do this.

Solutions I have tried:

a. I have tried importing it as a .csv but only the names appeared in the new group, no e-mails.

b. I tried importing as .xls but it produced range definition errors.

c. I tried exporting my current contacts into a .csv spreadsheet, deleting everything but the headers, and then filling in the information using the Outlook generated headers. When imported, the result was spotty with some blank contacts and no e-mail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I have try this and work for me
see if it helps you.

1.Change your view to a table view like the “Phone List” viewOutlook 2010
Home tab-> group: Current View-> Phone

2.Insert and arrange the columns you want to export to Excel
Tab View-> group: Arrangement-> button Add Columns

3.Press OK until all the open screens are closed.

4.Press CTRL+A to select al your contacts.

5.Press CTRL+C to copy your selected Contacts.

6.Open up Excel and select cell A1.

7.Press CTRL+V to paste all contact information or use the Paste button on the Ribbon or on the Toolbar.

8.Save your Excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

I have Outlook 2016, so the process will be a little different, but the overall steps should be very similar.

First, get your Excel data. Change your column headers to `Name`, `E-Mail`, `Company`. This way will save you having to remap them later, although that's still possible.

[image]

Next, head to Outlook and go to `Contacts`. First, I'd recommend creating a new folder in your contacts with any name you want, so they aren't mixed with all your other contacts (at least initially, whilst making the new Contact Group). I just called it `Group1`.

[image]

In Outlook 2016, from here I choose `File`, `Open & Export`, `Import/Export`.

[image]

Choose `Import from another program or file`, followed by `Comma Separated Values`. Point to your CSV file, and choose whether you'd like duplicates (Safest option is of course `Allow Duplicates`, although your new folder should be empty anyway). Choose the destination folder to be your new Contacts folder called `Group1` and hit next. Now, on this screen, choose `Map Custom Fields...` to verify your fields are mapped correctly:

[image]

Scroll down and make sure the mappings are visible in the right hand column (Name - Name, Company - Company and E-Mail - E-Mail). If you named your columns as above, this shouldn't need any changing.

[image]

Finish up here to import your contacts. Now create a new `Contact Group`, add new members and navigate to your `Group1` folder. Add all the members and give it a name, you're done.

[image]

Of course, you can use any spreadsheet as long as you map the fields correctly in the step before (Drag the column header from the left column to the matching field on the right column).

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work in 2010.   The key was getting the headers right and exporting the excel file to MS DOS .csv,  (as opposed to just .csv) and then importing it the same way.